# Internet not working despite LAN connected!

Tags: networking

I am using 16.04, LAN connected but internet not working.  WiFi works. How to solve this situation? Is any troubleshooting option available to identify the issue behind it?
Thanks
Raghul

Comment: Please, can you give us more detail. Give us output from command `ifconfig` or `ip a`.

Comment: enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:00:6a:fc:e7:8c  
          inet addr:10.10.34.3  Bcast:10.10.34.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8f2e:4882:262e:f7f0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:546 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:318 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42860 (42.8 KB)  TX bytes:25936 (25.9 KB)

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:185355 (185.3 KB)  TX bytes:185355 (185.3 KB)

Comment: wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:59:71:04:56:cd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: The above 3 are from command ifconfig

Comment: Based on your output I see that you have ip only on enp2s0 aka ethernet card. Can you give me output from commands `route -n` and output whet try to `traceroute 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.34.254    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.10.34.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0

Comment: Above comment is from for route -n       There are some commands appear during booting. The following appears-- DHCP .../ .   Also it says press F12 for network booting

Comment: Your default gw is `10.10.34.254`, can you ping it? If you can, your ethernet card is properly configured and work. After pinging a default gateway please do `traceroute 8.8.8.8`.